# Changing color of EditText in Fragment/Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, colors, android-edittext, fragment

I will change the input Color. How can I do this?
Found nothing on the web. I do not have a xml File. I create the `EditText` directly in the Fragment.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setTextColor Method

```
final EditText inputField = new EditText(getActivity());
inputField.setTextColor(Color.RED);//your Color
or

 inputField.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#636161"));//your Color code
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks for help.